# Half-automatic scrolling with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, scroll

I have several fullscreen sections on my page and I would like to use jQuery to detect a small scroll from the user and and scroll the page one section higher or lower automatically. So the user can only see one fullscreen section at a time not randomly scrolling between them.  Everything I tried was laggy and incomplete.

By the way, I would like it to work like Pollen's scrolling: http://pollenlondon.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/kot32qkc/

Code is not optimized but you'll have the main idea...

```
// if you're scrolling down
if(dir=="down") {
    // go to #s3 section
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#s3").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

see the jsfiddle for full code working.